# Using shingles and fuzziness in Elasticsearch Python DSL?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, querydsl, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

How do you call shingles in [Python DSL](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py)?

This is a simple example that searches for a phrase in the "name" field and another one in the "surname" field.

```
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q

def make_dsl_query(fields):
    """
    Construct a query
    """
    es_client = Elasticsearch()
    my_query = Search(using=es_client, index="my_index", doc_type="my_type")

    if fields['name'] and fields['surname']:
        my_query = my_query.query(Q('bool', should=
                   [Q("match", name=fields['name']),
                    Q("match", surname=fields['surname'])]))
    return my_query


if __name__ == '__main__':

    my_query = make_dsl_query(fields={"name": "Ivan The Terrible", "surname": "Conqueror of the World"})
    response = my_query.execute()

    # print response
    for hit in response:
        print(hit.meta.score, hit.name, hit.surname)
```

1) Is it possible to use shingles? And how? I've tried many things and can't find anything in the documentation on it.

This would work in a normal Elasticsearch query, but apparently called in a different way in the Python DSL...

```
my_query = my_query.query(Q('bool', should=
                   [Q("match", name.shingles=fields['name']),
                    Q("match", surname.shingles=fields['surname'])]))
```

2) How do I pass fuzziness parameters to my match? Can't seem to find anything on it either. Ideally I would be able to do something like this:

```
my_query = my_query.query(Q('bool', should=
                   [Q("match", name=fields['name'], fuzziness="AUTO", max_expansions=10),
                    Q("match", surname=fields['surname'])]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use shingles you need to define them in your mappings, it's too late to try and use them in query time. At query time what you can do is use a `match_phrase` query.

> ```
> my_query = my_query.query(Q('bool', should=
>                [Q("match", name.shingles=fields['name']),
>                 Q("match", surname.shingles=fields['surname'])]))
> ```

This should work if written as:

```
 my_query = my_query.query(Q('bool', should=
               [Q("match", name__shingles=fields['name']),
                Q("match", surname__shingles=fields['surname'])]))
```

Assuming you have the `shingles` field defined on both `name` and `surname` fields.

Note that you can also use the `|` operator:

```
 my_query = Q("match", name__shingles=fields['name']) | Q("match", surname.shingles=fields['surname'])
```

instead of constructing the `bool` query yourself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do I go about allowing fuzziness, though? For now, I just ended up making a dictionary with the needed query for fuzzy search and transforming it into Q object with Q({...}). Is there a better way to pass parameters to the query? The source code indicates that the query doesn't allow any additional parameters.

Comment: of course, `Q("match", name__shingles={'query': fields['name'], 'fuzziness': 'AUTO'})` should work just fine - the kwargs are essentially just keys in the resulting json.

Answer (score 3):

**As of January, 2023**: elasticsearch-dsl does support fuzzy matches, but it's just not very well documented.

For simple fuzzy matches:

```py
Q('fuzzy', fieldName=matchString)
```

When you want to set a custom fuzziness:

```py
Q({"fuzzy": {"yourFieldName": {"value": matchString, "fuzziness": fuzziness}}})
```

My understanding is that the `fuzzy` keyword is just a wrapper for a standard query, see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/elasticsearch_dsl/query.py#L362.

**Source**:

1. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/issues/1510 (solution courtesy of @leberknecht on github)